# My Camera Width is Blocked

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, camera, scale

I Was following one of the tutorials of Blender Guru and I think I have done some mistake that my camera has became like this.

[image: this is the photo look at my camera its too thin.]

[image: in the second photo you can clearly see what i am trying to say ..]

Render tab settings
[image]

i think mistake is here
[image]

Comment: please help me i am a absolute beginner

Comment: how can i is it in render tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your render resolution.
[image]
It can be found in the properties panel (the right-side one) under the render tab (the first one with the camera icon).
If that doesn't work, try changing the Aspect Ratio.
[image]

Comment: i tried it but it is not working

Comment: Can you post an image of your render tab?

Comment: Try changing the Aspect Ratio. It's just below the resolution.

Comment: added a image of my render tab

Comment: please provide a solution

Comment: when i am opening a new file it is fine but when im working on this file its always thin

Comment: Change the X and Y Aspect Ratio (can be found below the resolution) to 1

Comment: i tried it but nothing happened

Comment: camera just went a little bit more big

Comment: i am posting one more image tell me what have i done wrong

Comment: Your current X and Y aspect ratios are 1:200 which is not proportional. It means that the Y axis of your camera is 200 times bigger than your X axis and this is certainly not you want.

Comment: i posted a image

Comment: and can you tell me aspect ratio what to set

Comment: As told earlier, set X and Y aspect Ratios to 1 and set the resolution as per the quality of the image you want. I would suggest to set the image resolution to 1920x1080 if you want an HD image.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another image. Check that out.